# Adding Delete to content inside textarea similar to Email Client

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jquery autocomplete to add the value to my textbox. I want to add functionality EXACTLY LIKE any email service. You add an email it turns into a box and you can delete it from the textbox. Or the EXACT WAY you can add tags to your questions on here. If need be textarea doesn't matter just trying to get something like what emails have.

My autocomplete function is just adding the value to my textbox with id '#name'

```
    $("#name").autocomplete({
    minLength: 3,
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.getJSON("/getData", {
            term: extractLast(request.term)
        }, response);
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        var terms = split(this.value);
        terms.pop();
        if(ui.item.label == 'Create New') {
            $('.add-user').show();
        }
            terms.push(ui.item.label);
            terms.push("");
            this.value = terms.join(", ");
            //Get the ids associated with the name selected adding to a hidden field called #userId
            var id = split($('#userId').val());
            id.pop();
            id.push(ui.item.id);
            id.push("");
            $('#userId').val(id.join());
            return false;

    },
    focus: function () {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to reinvent the wheel

Look up the select2 library for jquery:

https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags

Cheers! :)